# AngularJS give active class to button in button group

Tags: angularjs

I have a button group with some buttons, two created with html and others are created with a ng-repeat. I want that on click the button have an active class so I can custom it to show it's activated.

So here is what I do :

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example"
     ng-init="selectedTab = 'raw'">

  <button class="btn"
     ng-click="selectView('raw'); selectedTab = 'raw'; console.log(selectedTab);"
     ng-class="{'active':selectedTab === 'raw'}">Raw data
  </button>
  <button class="btn"
     ng-click="selectView('summary'); selectedTab = 'summary'; console.log(selectedTab);"  
     ng-class="{'active':selectedTab === 'summary'}">Summary
  </button>

  <button class="btn" ng-repeat="(key, value) in views"
          ng-click="selectView(key); selectedTab = key; console.log(selectedTab);"
          ng-class="{'active':selectedTab === key}">
    {{ key }}
  </button>
</div>
```

My problem is that for the two first one all works fine, when I click on the first button the class active is added, and when I click on the second the class is removed from the first one and added to the second one.

The problem is about the buttons generated by the ng-repeat, when I click on them it's add the active class to the button but when I click on another button it's not removing the class, so they can all have the activate class.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that `ng-repeat` creates its own local scope so any variables you reference there that are not defined on the parent scope will be created locally. Although you can put multiple commands in `ng-click` it is discouraged - it also seems that doing so will not cause a digest cycle for those items inside the `ng-repeat`.

You can resolve all of this by making `selectedTab` a property on your controller and having the `selectView` method set the value of `selectedTab`. Here's a quick example:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', ($scope) => {
    $scope.selectedTab = 'raw';
    $scope.views = {
      Detail1: 'details',
      Detail2: 'details',
      Detail3: 'details'
      };
      
      $scope.selectView = function(view) {
        $scope.selectedTab = view;
      }
  });
```

```css
.active {
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div class="btn-group" 
       role="group" 
       aria-label="Basic example">
    <button class="btn" 
            ng-click="selectView('raw')" 
            ng-class="{'active':selectedTab === 'raw'}">Raw data</button>
    <button class="btn" 
            ng-click="selectView('summary')" 
            ng-class="{'active':selectedTab === 'summary'}">Summary</button>

    <button class="btn" 
            ng-repeat="(key, value) in views" 
            ng-click="selectView(key)" 
            ng-class="{'active':selectedTab === key}">
      {{ key }}
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

New AngularJS developers often do not realize that `ng-repeat`, `ng-switch`, `ng-view`, `ng-include` and `ng-if` all create new child scopes, so the problem often shows up when these directives are involved.

The assignment `selectedTab = key` is being done on the child scope created by the `ng-repeat` directive. The solution is to do the assignment to a property of an object:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example"
     ng-init="selected = {tab:'raw'}">

  <button class="btn"
     ng-click="selectView('raw'); selected.tab = 'raw';"
     ng-class="{'active':selected.tab === 'raw'}">Raw data
  </button>
  <button class="btn"
     ng-click="selectView('summary'); selected.tab = 'summary';"  
     ng-class="{'active':selected.tab === 'summary'}">Summary
  </button>

  <button class="btn" ng-repeat="(key, value) in views"
          ng-click="selectView(key); selected.tab = key;"
          ng-class="{'active':selected.tab === key}">
    {{ key }}
  </button>
</div>
```

For more information, see [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs)